# Conditional associated models with children models CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, associations, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

I have the following db structure:

```
// Contacts
,----,------------,------------------,
| id | name       | email            |
|----|------------|------------------|
| 1  | John Doe   | john@example.com |
'----'------------'------------------'

// Jobs
,----,------------,-------------------,
| id | title      | description       |
|----|------------|-------------------|
| 1  | Fancy Job  | This job is fancy |
'----'------------'-------------------'

// JobRequests
,----,------------,------------,----------,
| id | job_id     | contact_id | accepted |
|----|------------|------------|----------|
| 1  | 1          | 1          | yes      |
| 2  | 1          | 2          | no       |
'----'------------'------------'----------'
```

And I want all the contacts that have accepted a job.

I've tried doing the following:

```
$jobs = $this->Jobs
    ->find('all')
    ->where(['event_id' => $id])
    ->contain([
        'JobRequests' => [
            function(Query $query) {
                return $query->where(['JobRequests.accepted' => 'yes']);
            },
            'Contacts'
        ]
    ]);
```

But then I get a {{Unsupported operand types}} error. And the [docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#passing-conditions-to-contain) don't really say what you should do, should you want a condition and a contain.

How would I do this?

EDIT:
I want data to look like this:

```
Job 1:
     Accepted by John Doe
     Accepted by Jane Doe
Job 2:
     Accepted by Foo Bar
Job 3:
     Nobody accepted
```

Comment: For starters, shouldn't you query the `Contacts` table if you want to receive contacts? Are you sure that you posted the correct code, respectively that you've correctly described what you're trying to achieve? It always helps if you describe the types of associations, and show an example data set of what you expect the results to look like.

Comment: Well I need to query the jobs table, because I need to find the list of jobs, and people who accepted those jobs.

Comment: In that case it's just that the "syntax" is wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong "syntax", you can't just pass a callable inside an options array.

Further below in the docs that you've linked there's an example how to nest query builders and pass additional conditions... the `queryBuilder` option:

```
->contain([
    'JobRequests' => [
        'queryBuilder' => function(Query $query) {
            return $query->where(['JobRequests.accepted' => 'yes']);
        },
        'Contacts'
    ]
])
```

Stacking the containments should also work:

```
->contain([
    'JobRequests' => function(Query $query) {
        return $query->where(['JobRequests.accepted' => 'yes']);
    },
    'JobRequests.Contacts'
])
```

And nesting should work too:

```
->contain([
    'JobRequests' => function(Query $query) {
        return $query
            ->where(['JobRequests.accepted' => 'yes'])
            ->contain(['Contacts']);
    }
])
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Eager Loading Associations Via Contain](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#eager-loading-associations-via-contain)**
- **[API > \Cake\ORM\Query::contain()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.6/class-Cake.ORM.Query.html#_contain)**